# How to make layout Flexible in all versions of iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autoresizingmask

I have made an app which runs fine on `iPhone6` but when I switch to `iPhone5s` and `iPhone5` my layout completely distracts. Every `Control` Changes its position.

How can I  make my `app` to run on all versions of `iPhones` fine without breaking the `layout`.

I have disabled the `Auto Layout` and I am Using `AutoResizing` from `InterfaceBuilder`.

Comment: I recommend autolayout, any Resonanz you switched it off?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situations with my apps.

If you try make flexible in all devices using Autoresizing, you will have a lot of problems to do that, because the Xcode 6 (Interface Builder) is based to use with AutoLayout and Size Classes. In my apps, I have strange behaviors without them so... I recommend like @Volker, use AutoLayout (and size Classes), but if you don't want it or you don't have time at this moment...

You must create a Storyboard for any device screens or you must program to adjust your interface for every device. If you found another way to do that, please share it.